# Best / Proper way to play a short sound

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to play a short sound in my Swift app.
The sound I want to play :

- is very short (less than five seconds) ;
- is one of the system sound (ex: sms received) ;
- will most likely be played multiple time during the life cycle of my application ;
- can be fired two time in less than the sound length time (i.e. fire the first one and a second one is fired before the first finish playing) ;

In addition to this, I would like to :

- hear the sound only if the application is active and the "silent mode" is off ;
- make the phone vibrate (regardless if silent mode is on or off).

So far, here is what I have :

```
import AVFoundation

class SoundPlayer {
    // Singleton
    class var sharedInstance : SoundPlayer {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : SoundPlayer = SoundPlayer()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    // Properties
    var error:NSError?
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound", ofType: "wav")!) // Working
    //let soundURL = NSURL(string:"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sms-received1.caf") // Working
    //let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle(identifier: "com.apple.UIKit")!.pathForResource("sms-received1", ofType: "caf")!) // Not working (crash at runtime)

    init() {
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL, error: &error)

        if (error != nil) {
            println("[SoundPlayer] There was an error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func playSound() {
        if (audioPlayer.playing) {
            audioPlayer.stop()
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

What I understand there are several ways to play a sound.
The two most common ways seems to be : `AVAudioPlayer` (like I did) and `AudioToolbox`.

From there, I'm asking myself three questions :

1. Which of those two is the most adapted (best / proper) for my situation ? *(`AVAudioPlayer` is working correctly at the moment)*
2. - Are we allowed to play a system sound ? *(Very small gain in size if in don't add my own sound to the project)*
   - If so, is `NSURL(string:"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sms-received1.caf")` a good way to retrieve the sound ? Any better / proper solution ?
3. Is there a way to vibrate the phone at the same time the sound is fired ?